# SAS: Calculating sum within each group

Tags: sas

```
data cumsum;
   set temp;
   by group;
   if first.group then sum = 0;
   sum + x
   if last.group then output;
run;
```

The code above calculates sum within each group, but if I change `sum + x` to `sum = sum + x`, the result is not correct. Could anyone explain what the difference between `sum + x` and `sum = sum + x`?

Comment: The duplicate discusses the `sum` function as well, but at least one of the good answers discusses all three options.

Answer (score 2):

The `sum+x;` notation has an implicit `retain` statement added when the code runs.

If you use the `sum = sum + x;` notation, you must explicitly state the retain statement manually.  Ie.

```
data cumsum;
  set temp;
  by group;
  retain sum 0;
  if first.group then sum = 0;
  sum = sum + x
  if last.group then output;
run;
```